# This java mosquito keeps biting me- NoClassDefFoundError. Spray ! Spray ! Spray ! ..& Nothing happens

Tags: path, environment-variables, classpath, noclassdeffounderror, java-home

I am trying to use a bunch of JAVA apps and I keep hitting this wall. I looked up and followed pretty much everything out there that could cure it. But this is a JAVA super bug mosquito. Pl tell what is happening

```
    C:\Users\Administrator>java -version
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object

C:\Users\Administrator>where java
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe

C:\Users\Administrator>echo %java_home%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45

C:\Users\Administrator>echo %path%
C:\PROGRAM FILES\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT SHARED\WINDOWS LIVE;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT SHARED\WINDOWS LIVE;C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\
2\WINDOWSPOWERSHELL\V1.0\;;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\INTEL\OPENCL SDK\2.0\BIN\X86;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\INTEL\OPENCL SDK\2.0\BIN\X64;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON
M FILES (X86)\WINDOWS LIVE\SHARED;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\WINSCP\;C:\PROGRAMDATA\CHOCOLATEY\BIN;c:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;c:\Program Files\WID
ram Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin

C:\Users\Administrator>echo %classpath%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\lib
```

I also have JRE installed but I removed it from the PATH ( i.e. the bin dir of JRE as also that of Oracle's ) to make sure there is JUST one exe for Java.
I get this error in spite of that.
I am on windows 7

Answer (score 0):

The problem was rt.jar needed for the java.lang.Object wasn't there in the lib dir.
My 32 bit JRE was working. Just 64 quit.  Transplanting RT.jar from x86 to x64 from lib did not work so I uninstalled and reinstalled JDK ( with JRE ) and it ran well. 
The rt.jar got prolly removed by Trend AntiVirus scan